# Resolving Cyclical Reference in Referential Relationships

Tags: database-design, referential-integrity, sql-server-compact

I'm designing a small SQL Server Compact Edition database and am attempting to enforce referential integrity. The database is a simple backend for a small desktop application that functions as an account/password manager.

Here are my relationships:

[image]

Now, I'm attempting to set CASCADE delete rules like so:

```
category.id ---> account.category_id
account.id ---> credential.account_id
category.id ---> field.category_id
field.id ---> credential.field_id
```

After adding the first 3 relationships, I get an error while adding the 4th (field ---> credential):

*The referential relationship will result in a cyclical reference that is not allowed.*

I'm struggling to determine why this is happening and how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using CASCADE? [Use a trigger](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/).

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Compact Edition which doesn't support triggers.

Comment: Sorry, missed the tag. *shrug* Does compact edition support delete statements you write yourself, in the right order, rather than relying on cascade?

Comment: Yes, it does. I was hoping to avoid that route but it looks like it might be the only solution (also making it the best solution =D).

Comment: By the way, that is not (and should not be) called "Cyclical Reference", there is no cycle. It's "Multiple Cascade Paths".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server Compact Edition, which doesn't support [triggers that could solve this issue](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/), my recommendation is either:

- write your own manual `DELETE` statements in the proper order, rather than use `CASCADE`
- change the design
- use Express / LocalDB instead of Compact Edition, which is extremely limited and [has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20364011/61305)

Comment: That sounds fair to me. I'm too far in to switch platforms, but manually writing the DELETE statements seems like a viable option to me.

Thanks.